# Consuming a paginated API in a reactive style

Tags: java, pagination, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm trying to figure out how to consume a paginated API in a reactive style, exposing a stream of items instead of the pages that the API gives me.

#### What I Have - A Paginated API

The Slack API (and many others) handle pagination with some form of meta-data object, so that on a query to `/api/stuff` you get back an object like this:

```
{
    "items": [ <list of first page you requested> ],
    "meta": {
        "cursor": "<a cursor string to get the next page>"
    }
}
```

You can then request the next page with `GET /api/stuff?cursor=<the cursor from above>`, and in the response you'll get a new cursor, and so you can keep going until you get a response where the cursor is empty - that was then the last available page.

#### What I Want - A Stream of Items

With Reactor, I'd like to provide a method with the return type `Flux<Item>`, i.e. a stream of all items where the consumer doesn't need to know or care that the items are actually fetched one page at a time.

Basically, I'd like to do something that takes an initial state and a method with the signature `State -> Mono<Tuple2<Collection<Item>, State>>` (or equivalent) and gives me a `Flux<Item>` by sequentially fetching new pages, until the `State` indicates that we are done.

I've tried to formulate something using `Flux.create` or `Flux.generate` but it seems their use cases  are slightly different from mine.

#### How Do I Get There?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a reactor newbie, but I think this is what [expand()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#expand-java.util.function.Function-) is for:

Here is a complete demo, where `getFirstPage()` and `getNextPage()`simulate the slack API. `getNextPage()` returns the last page when the cursor reaches the value 5.

```
public class Slack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getFirstPage().expand(page -> getNextPage(page))
                      .flatMapIterable(page -> page.getResult())
                      .subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Mono<Page> getFirstPage() {
        System.out.println("getting first page");
        return Mono.just(new Page(Arrays.asList("page0-1", "page0-2"), 1));
    }

    private static Mono<Page> getNextPage(Page page) {
        System.out.println("getting page " + page.getCursor());
        if (page.getCursor() == null) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        Integer nextCursor = (page.getCursor() == 5) ? null : page.getCursor() + 1;
        return Mono.just(new Page(Arrays.asList("page" + page.getCursor() + "-1", "page" + page.getCursor() + "-2"), nextCursor));
    }

    static class Page {
        private List<String> result;
        private Integer cursor;

        public Page(List<String> result, Integer cursor) {
            this.result = result;
            this.cursor = cursor;
        }

        public List<String> getResult() {
            return result;
        }

        public Integer getCursor() {
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. i used this concept to handle pagination. just want to confirm, when `Mono.empty()` is returned, it will exit the `expand` chain and `flatMap` whatever the existing iterable is?